# How to write a shell script to read from standard in and print to standard out?

Tags: bash, shell, scripting, stdout, stdin

This is my first time dabbling with scripting.

I'm trying to write a shell script to read stdin, then wherever there is a ":" split it into 2 variables and add a "!" after the ":".

I know I need to utilize "read" utility to split words into separate variables, but other than that I'm not too sure.

I could do this in a matter of minutes in Java, C++, or Python.

Thanks for your help guys, I appreciate it.

Comment: The example for "read" basically tells you how to do this: http://www.lehman.cuny.edu/cgi-bin/man-cgi?read+1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems like you're asking how to implement a Java/C++/Python pattern in Bash. Since Bash is quite different from these languages, the answer you get is likely to be clumsy and non-idiomatic.

Consider explaining what you have and what you want instead.

If you have

```
foobar
foo:bar
foo:bar:baz
```

and you want

```
foobar
foo:!bar
foo:!bar:baz
```

Then you could go the Java/etc route, as you describe: read and check for a `:` and if so split it and add a `!`, and write it out:

```
# Bad way
while IFS= read -r line
do
    if [[ $line == *:* ]]
    then
        first=${line%%:*}
        second=${line#*:}
        echo "$first:!$second"
    else
        echo "$line"
    fi
done
```

However, since Bash isn't Java/etc, we have different tools and techniques at our disposal, and can simply do:

```
sed -e 's/:/:!/'
```

Comment: In the "bad way", can you tell me why you need the double brackets? Because when I run this in the command line it states that "[[: not found."

That being said, next time I will explain better what I have and what I want

Comment: @cmonnats23, the first line of your script should be `#!/bin/bash` otherwise there is indeed a chance that it won't work.

Comment: @cmonnats23 like @thom says, this happens if you use `#!/bin/sh`, running your script with old `sh` instead of the newer `bash`. Since you tagged the post with `bash`, I used bash specific features like `[[ ]]`